# How to find value in dictionary using key and then search the value within the tuple(value of dictionary)?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the data that I have: You can see that it is a dictionary with a string key and then multiple tuples to it. I am trying to write a lookup function in order to use the key string and the toll string to lookup the value (float).

```
dict1 = {'20MAY17': [('TOLL2', 9817.73), ('TOLL3', 8395.49)], '23MAY17': [('TOLL2', 6497.36), ('TOLL4', 6827.51)], '13MAY17': [('TOLL4', 9803.42)], '5MAY17': [('TOLL3', 6677.66)], '16MAY17': [('TOLL4', 1565.78), ('TOLL3', 7949.97), ('TOLL2', 3739.91)], '12MAY17': [('TOLL2', 5680.84)], '6MAY17': [('TOLL2', 2420.46)], '28MAY17': [('TOLL3', 6405.19), ('TOLL4', 1358.27)], '22MAY17': [('TOLL4', 4022.52), ('TOLL3', 8823.13)], '11MAY17': [('TOLL4', 4832.2699999999995)], '27MAY17': [('TOLL3', 8878.97)], '17MAY17': [('TOLL4', 4150.74)], '3MAY17': [('TOLL3', 5729.33)], '24MAY17': [('TOLL4', 1452.02), ('TOLL1', 3860.73)], '8MAY17': [('TOLL1', 9863.36)], '18MAY17': [('TOLL1', 4584.25)], '15MAY17': [('TOLL1', 8640.64)]}
```

The dictionary is called dict1.

Here is the function, I am using user input.

```
def lookup(dict1, str1, str2):
    print(dict1[str1][str2])
```

It should do something like this:

```
lookup(dict1, '20MAY17', 'TOLL2')
```

9817.73

```
lookup(dict1, '20MAY17', 'TOLL3')
```

8395.49

Comment: Why not have a dict inside of a dict? Then your current code would work fine.

Comment: The guidelines are to have the dictionary return in this form. Also, I dont know how to do what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

You can have dictionaries inside dictionaries. I would suggest to simply preprocess your data by (if your original data was stored in `original_data`)

```
data = dict((key, dict(tpl)) for key, tpl in original_data.items())
```

Then you can simply do a lookup by a double item lookup:

```
data['20MAY17']['TOLL2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform your data structure to a dictionary where the values dictionaries instead of lists of tuples. After that, lookup is trivial.

```
>>> d = {'20MAY17': [('TOLL2', 9817.73), ('TOLL3', 8395.49)], '23MAY17': [('TOLL2', 6497.36), ('TOLL4', 6827.51)]}
>>> d_better = {k:dict(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> d_better
{'20MAY17': {'TOLL2': 9817.73, 'TOLL3': 8395.49}, '23MAY17': {'TOLL4': 6827.51, 'TOLL2': 6497.36}}
>>> 
>>> def lookup(dict_, day, toll):
...     return dict_[day][toll]
... 
>>> lookup(d_better, '20MAY17', 'TOLL2')
9817.73
```

As you can see, the `lookup` function is somewhat unwarranted and you could write `d_better[day][toll]` directly.

Comment: I upvoted it, did not downvote it !! I dont know why it showed -1

Comment: Also when I do what you said. 
d_better['20MAY17']['TOLL2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    d_better['20MAY17']['TOLL2']
KeyError: '20MAY17'

I get a key error for some reason.

Comment: @AkshanDua There can be no other reason than a data entry error on your part. As you can see, `d_better` has the key `'20MAY17'` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to:

```
def lookup(dict1, str1, str2):
    print(dict(dict1.get(str1)).get(str2))
```

This works because the dict key is converted to a dict before the 2nd key is passed.